# access smb share via emacs tramp mode - repeatedly prompting for password

Tags: emacs, samba, smb, tramp

If I use `smbclient` from the command line on a unix host to access a windows server share (happens to be a windows server in an Active Directory domain), it works fine.  I can access directories and files on the server.  Here's the `smbclient` command that succeeds:

```
smbclient -U user -W domain -I ip_host //sharetop
```

So now I am trying to use tramp mode in emacs to open (`find-file`) the following url:

```
/smb:user%domain@ip_host:/sharetop
```

I get a password prompt as expected:

```
Password for /smb:user%domain@ip_host:
```

However, when I enter the **correct** password (same one that works with smbclient), it just shows me the password prompt again.  And the `*Messages*` buffer has:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for //user@ip_host/sharetop...failed
```

I'm looking for success stories with emacs tramp mode accessing files on smb urls that point to windows servers.  Or perhaps a way to get more information than just "failed".

**Update**
I set `tramp-verbose` ([Traces](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Traces-and-Profiles)) to 6, and that showed the smbclient command line:

```
smbclient -g -L ip_host -U user -W domain -s /dev/null
```

`-L` is intended for the netbios name.  In my case, I am using an IP address or DNS name.  So, it appears I'll have to figure out how to convince tramp/smb to accept an IP address instead of a netbios name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Tramp needs the `-L` parameter in order to apply also `-g`, grepping for the existing shares. Using `-I` would make it much harder to see the shares. Possible, but not implemented yet.

I recommend to write a feature request (aka bug report) either to the Tramp mailing list, or as Emacs bug report.